# How does the triangle inequality work here?

Tags: inequality, contour-integration, upper-lower-bounds

I was reading a proof about a complex contour integral recently, and saw a step which was a bit like $$\left|\frac1{R^2 e^{2i\theta}+1}\right|\le\frac1{R^2-1}$$
I tried to derive this. $$\left|\frac1{R^2e^{2i\theta}+1}\right|=\frac{\left|R^2e^{-2i\theta}+1\right|}{R^4+2R^2\cos2\theta+1}\le\frac{R^2+1}{R^4+2R^2\cos2\theta+1}$$But then I got stuck because the denominator does not factorise to cancel the numerator. How can this be shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One form of the triangle inequality is that $|x + y| \ge |x| - |y|$; prove this by applying the usual inequality to $|x| = |x + y - y|$. Then we have

$$|R^2 e^{2i\theta} + 1| \ge |R^2 e^{2i\theta}| - |1| = R^2 - 1.$$

Invert to get the desired result.

Comment: What if $R^2 < 1$?

Comment: Yes, good point, in which case the inequality is clearly false.

Comment: @EthanBolker This was in the context of a contour integral where $R$ is the radius of a large contour. We take $R\to\infty$. Sorry, perhaps I should have specified this in the question.

Comment: True. But if your argument doesn't use that extra hypothesis then you've proved something that isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

$|R^{2}e^{2i\theta}+1|\geq |R^{2}e^{2i\theta}|-1=R^{2}-1$ and then flipping over.

Comment: What if $R^2 < 1$?

Comment: OP has said the $R$ is large.

Answer (score 2):

The locus of points in the denominator is a circle of radius $R^2$ centered at $1+0i$. What's the closest such a point can be to the origin?

Note: this geometric argument tells you the inequality is wrong if $R^2 < 1$.

Comment: This was in the context of a contour integral where $R$ is the radius of a large contour. We take $R\to\infty$. Sorry, perhaps I should have specified this in the question. But yes, that argument makes sense for $R^2<1$. Thank you